# how to select MAX(updateTag)

Tags: php, mysql, passbook, mysql-select-db

I create digiCardPass with updateTag column that is timestamp. 
I try:

```
   $query1 = mysql_query("select MAX(updateTag) as updateTag from digiCardPass");
   $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
   $updateTag = $row1['updateTag'];
   error_log("max updateTag:",$updateTag,0);
```

But I cannot get this error in php_error.log:

> [03-May-2013 12:46:06 Asia/Phnom_Penh] PHP Notice:  A non well formed
>   numeric value encountered in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/createPass/index.php on line
>   42 [03-May-2013 12:46:06 Asia/Phnom_Penh] max updateTag:

```
   //line 42: error_log("max updateTag:",$updateTag,0);
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you tried by echoing the `$updateTag`? what is it give.

Comment: I just edit my question, you can take a look !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error_log statement is incorrect and is causing the error message.  You have a comma between your text and the variable that you want to write to the log, so it is treating the `$updateTag` as the second parameter of the error_log command.

Try:

```
error_log("max updateTag: " . $updateTag, 0);
```

to get rid of your warning and write the contents of `$updateTag` in the log

Comment: yes, thank you ! but after that , nothing shows ! I got to fix it up !

Comment: You mean you see `max updateTag:` in the log, or nothing at all?  If nothing at all then check to see if whatever condition this code is nested in is evaluating true.

Comment: yes, I can see, but when I select in other query by using this updateTag, I cannot get result !

Comment: How are you using it your other query?

Comment: I use it with where condition. This is the query: select passTypeID, authenticationToken as auth, auxiliaryFieldsPowerBy as aux, associatedStoreIdentifiers as asso, altTextBarcode as alt from digiCardPass where updateTag = '$updateTag'

Comment: I try to test this query in SQL already and It works, but not work in here !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at $row1['updateTag'] as it probably can't be formatted as a number by PHP.

```
echo $row1['updateTag'];
echo floatval($row1['updateTag']);
```

Get sure updateTag is a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
error_log("max updateTag:",1,$updateTag); // second var is type 0-3

Optional. Specifies the error log type. 
Possible log types:
0 - Default. The error is sent to the servers logging system or a file, depending on how the error_log configuration is set in the php.ini file
1 - The error is sent by email to the address in the destination parameter. This message type is the only one that uses the headers parameter
2 - The error is sent through the PHP debugging connection. This option is only available in PHP 3
3 - The error is added to the file destination string
```

Comment: `$updateTag` does not contain a filename and so is not a valid destination parameter.  The intention appears to be to echo the variable content to the log and your code will write "max updateTag:" to a filename with the name of the contents of the $updateTag variable.